# How to convert a large sparse matrix to an array(Details given below)?

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, scikit-learn, sparse-matrix

i have a sparse matrix of features formed as a result of following operations using sklearn:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(analyzer = "word",tokenizer = None,preprocessor = None,stop_words = None,max_features = 5000) 

train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(y)
```

Converting to the contiguous array representation would materialize all the zeros in memory and the resulting size would be:

```
train_data_features.shape[0] * train_data_features.shape[1] * train_data_features.dtype.itemsize / 1e6
```

which yields:`6242.4

That's 8GB, compared to less than 1MB for the original sparse representation.
So,how to tackle this problem so that I can efficiently fit the resulting array into a random forest classifier?

`

Comment: Most models in `scikit-learn`, including `RandomForestClassifier`, accept sparse matrix as input. You can fit directly with your sparse represented data.

Comment: Well,I did input it in the random forest classifier,but it's taking a lot of tome to complete hence had to interrupt the kernel(IPython)midway.Anyway to achieve it faster,perhaps?

Comment: @DiscoDancer, did you tried to set n_jobs=-1 in RandomForestClassifier? In your place i'd try to learn it on a small subset of dataset, to see if fit works fine on your configuration/input, then if you can't wait till completion of fit even with n_jobs=-1, you can try to compress feature space with FeatureHashing/PCA/ICA. Because i think that solving this problem will be much easier and faster than manipulations on 8gb matrix.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
m = np.memmap('train_data_features_dense.mmap', dtype=train_data_features.dtype, mode='w+', shape=train_data_features.shape)
train_data_features.todense(out=m)
# Some work with m here, if you want, reading, writing, etc
# Better to call delete when you've done all work with it, del will flush buffers automatically
del m
# If you want to load memmap in another script
m = np.memmap('train_data_features_dense.mmap', dtype=train_data_features.dtype, mode='r+', shape=train_data_features.shape)
```

But as @yangjie said above, you should operate on sparse matrices when you can.

Comment: @DiscoDancer, yes
import numpy as np

Comment: Its just gives a matrix with all zeroes.

Comment: @DiscoDancer, After you feeded it to todense method? Maybe it's because you can't see all values of this big matrix? Try to sum over some dimension or count all nonzero occurences.

Comment: Should I feed this m value to the classifier?

Comment: @DiscoDancer, yes, you can work with it as with traditional matrix, it will occupy as much RAM as possible, and load data from file into RAM lazily, but don't try to copy it into RAM.

Comment: I tried,and and it's eating my RAM,using top I saw on average memory consumption was 54%.My laptop got stuck.Anyway to get around this problem?(except obviously increasing my RAM)

Comment: @DiscoDancer,
Try to remove old train_data_features_dense.mmap file from HDD and create new one, but with float32 type as:


          m = np.memmap('train_data_features_dense.mmap', dtype=np.float32, mode='w+', shape=train_data_features.shape).


Then convert your sparse matrix with todense and try to fit RandomForest again.